# AutoMapper map Enum to SelectList - Selected value not working

Tags: c#, automapper, enumeration, automapper-3

I have created a map which convert an enum to a SelectList by using a custom implementation of ITypeConverter.

```
public class DeliveryModeToSelectListTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<ProductDeliveryMode, SelectList>
{
    public SelectList Convert( ResolutionContext context ) {
        ProductDeliveryMode pdm = (ProductDeliveryMode)context.SourceValue;
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem sli1 = new SelectListItem() {
            Text = StringEnum.GetStringValue( ProductDeliveryMode.DeliveryModeActivationByPin ),
            Value = ( (int)ProductDeliveryMode.DeliveryModeActivationByPin ).ToString(),
            Selected = (pdm == ProductDeliveryMode.DeliveryModeActivationByPin)
        };
        items.Add( sli1 );

        [...other enum members here...]

        SelectList sl = new SelectList( items, "Value", "Text", pdm );
        return sl;
    }
}
```

And then I have created a Map by using

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductDeliveryMode, SelectList>()
      .ConvertUsing( new DeliveryModeToSelectListTypeConverter() );
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>()
    .ForMember( p => p.DeliveryModeOptions, opt => opt.MapFrom( x => x.DeliveryMode ) )
    [...other members here...]
    .Include<ExperienceProduct, ExperienceProductViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ExperienceProduct, ExperienceProductViewModel>()
    .IncludeBase<Product, ProductViewModel>()
));
```

Everything seems to works very nice except from the fact that the `Selected` value of the `SelectListItem` does not maintains its value. I have been able to step into the code and the `SelectListItem` `sli1` it's correctly created with the selected value equal to `true`.

[image: Value when mapping]

However when i check that value after a mapping the value is always `false` as you can see from the following screenshots.

[image: Value after mapping]

Where do I am wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you create the select list:

```
SelectList sl = new SelectList( items, "Value", "Text", pdm);
```

You're passing the selected item as `pdm` of type `ProductDeliveryMode`, which is being compared against the `Value` property of type `string`.

From your comment below, the solution was to pass `pdm` as a string.

Comment: Well, your suggestion did'nt worked. But actually made me thinking to a difference. When I am passing inline the `pdm` that is of type `ProductDeliveryMode` while the `Value` member of the `SelectListItem` object is of type string. I ended up with passing the `pdm` object after having it converted to string. And everything di worked! If you correct your answer I will be glad to accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Oh great, I wasn't exactly sure how SelectList worked behind the scenes, but the different type for `pdm` is what made me suspicious. I will update the answer.